# Searching for a string within an array using for loop. Am I doing this right?

Tags: java

I would appreciate it if someone can help understand what am I doing wrong in this logic. I have a function which prompts user for a name, and then runs a for loop to see if any matches are found from an array. I am able to do the search and found records, my issue is that the "if statement" stops working as soon as I include the "else statement". I thank you for all your help.

Code:

```
public static void SearchByName(){  
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );       
    String answer;
    String name;

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("\nEnter Name: ");
    name = input.next();

    for(int i = 0; i < counter; ++i){

        if(records[i].str1.equals(name)){
            System.out.println("MATCHES FOUND: " + i);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("NO MATCHES FOUND");
            break;
        }

    }

    //PROMPT USER FOR MAIN MENU
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("\nPress \"m\" for SEARCH MAIN MENU");

    input = new Scanner( System.in );
    answer = input.next();

    if( answer.equals("m")){
        doMainMenu();
    }


}//METHOD
```

Comment: You need to loop through all your array to see if one element match. Why are you breaking your loop in you else? If the first element is not the one you search, you will break your for loop and don't search for the other ones.

Comment: Are you supposed to output that you found a match, or the number of matches you found?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is breaking out of your loop in the "else" if the first element doesn't match; so you never get to compare the second element.

Comment: What if statement are we talking about here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boolean found = false;
for(int i = 0; i < counter; ++i){

    if(records[i].str1.equals(name)){
        System.out.println("MATCH FOUND");
        found = true;
        break;
    }

}
if(!found) {
    System.out.println("NO MATCHES FOUND");
}
```

Comment: Also, do you want the search to be case-sensitive or case-insensitive? At the moment it is case sensitive.

Comment: It would be fantastic if search is case-insensitive. Your code has been a very big help. I have just learned how to go about such searches. How can I make case-insensitive search?

Comment: use .equalsIgnoreCase(name) instead of .equals(name)

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop will stop at the first time the `equals` method would return false.

For example if you search "Bob" in the array `[Alice,Tod,Bob]`, the first `equals` evaluation will return false and the loop end on the break.
It would work only if "Bob" is the first element of the array.

To solve that you can replace the `break` in the else statement with a `continue`. Note that in that case only the first index of the element may be returned (in case you have more than one occurences of the same String in your array).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that for the first array position the string does not match with the name you're searching for, so the `else` statement is going to be executed. As you have a `break` inside the else, it's going to stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code in in the for loop. The key word break, mean stop for loop;

```
   for(int i = 0; i < counter; ++i){
        if(records[i].str1.equals(name)){
            System.out.println("MATCHES FOUND: " + i);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("NO MATCHES FOUND");
            break;
        }
    }
```

The loop will be executed only once as the `break` is called regardless of the result of `records[i].str1.equals(name)`.

Just remove the second break and the code will run.

Tip: 
The message that matches was not found should be displayed when all potential matches ware checked.

Answer (score 0):

What you did wrong is that your else statement breaks your for loop if the name you're looking for is not at the first index of your array. Even if you remove break it will print out "NO MATCHES FOUND" after every failed attempt. In my opinion you should remove else statement completely from your for loop and place your print function right after the for loop in case name wasn't inside the array or in case you want to keep it inside for loop you can do it this way:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < counter; ++i){

        if(records[i].str1.equals(name)){
            System.out.println("MATCHES FOUND: " + i);
            break;
        } else if (i == counter-1) {

            System.out.println("NO MATCHES FOUND");

        }

    }
```

This way for loop passed through the whole field and if the name of the person isn't even at the last index of the field it will print out "NO MATCHES FOUND". Hopefully my comment helped you to understand what you did wrong. If you have any further questions feel free to ask.